# Cannot fill Jcombobox from database in java

Tags: java, database, swing, jcombobox

I'm Trying to get Information from a database to fill a Jcombobox, I'm trying to use the following codes but they are not working, in all of them the combo box is not being cleaned when.

Fisrt Attempt

```
try {
                    con = Connectionz.getConnection();//Connection Object 
                    pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * AS achooserfill FROM Login_Users WHERE [C Team Lead] =?");
                    pst.setString(1, va);
                    rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        achooser.removeAll();
                        achooser.addItem("Please select agent");
                        achooser.addItem(rs.getString("achooserfill"));

           }
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.err.println(e);
     }
```

Second Attempt

```
 try {
                con = Connectionz.getConnection();//Connection Object 
                pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Login_Users WHERE [C Team Lead] =?");
                pst.setString(1, va);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    achooser.removeAll();
                    achooser.addItem("Please select agent");
                    achooser.addItem(rs.getString("[VA #]"));

       }
 }catch(Exception e){
     System.err.println(e);
 }
```

Third Attempt

```
 try {
                con = Connectionz.getConnection();//Connection Object 
                pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT [VA #] FROM Login_Users WHERE [C Team Lead] =?");
                pst.setString(1, va);
                rs = pst.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    achooser.removeAll();
                    achooser.addItem("Please select agent");
                    achooser.addItem(rs.getString("[VA #]"));

       }
 }catch(Exception e){
     System.err.println(e);
 }
```

In all of the cases the result is the same,

[image: Error in JCombobox]

I Would really appreciate any kind of info or any resource to fix the situation

Comment: You're problem likely isn't with the resultset retrieval. Can you share the code in which you declare and configure `achooser`?

Comment: What is `va`? Have you tried executing your SQL queries? What does `SELECT * FROM Login_Users WHERE [C Team Lead] = ?` returns when you substitute `?` with `va` and run it?

Comment: Also (Just Curious), why are you adding `Please select agent` to your ComboBox for each and every result?

Comment: @BillHorvath I Just created de [chooser] I just create the object with netbeans, do I need to create the object with code and define an specific feature to allow it? (I'm newbie sorry)

Comment: @user2004685 thanks for you quick response, va is a variable that is defined as soon the user sign in it's a unique number to identify an user. and if I substitute ? it doesn't work, and  you're right I have to  take out those two request from the while, thanks!!!

Comment: And all your loops start with renoveAll. What is the point of using a loop when you WIPE all existing content in each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in all of them the combo box is not being cleaned.

```
achooser.removeAll();
```

The `removeAll()` method is a method of the `Container`, not the combo box.

You want:

```
achooser.removeAllItems();
```

to remove the items from the combo box.

And that statement should be outside of the loop.

Also, for something like this did you even verify that your ResultSet contains data. First you should just hardcode the data to prove that the `addItem()` method works. Then once you know that logic is working you make the code more dynamic by getting the data from the database.

Comment: thank you now the Combobox is clear, but that's the only Item that's available on the Combobox, the thing now is fill the box with the noew info.

Comment: @AlexGalvis, I already told you how to solve this problem. First just add hard coded data to prove that your code is being executed. Then once that works you get the data from the database. So you need to add debug code to the verify your loop is even executing and you are getting valid data. Don't assume you ResultSet contains data. Prove it with some debug code. If your ResultSet has data then the addItem(...) method will work.

Comment: thanks for anything I just used the resultset to table to see what I was getting and is empty. I'll change the query and test it YOU ARE AWSOME!

Comment: @AlexGalvis, `I just used the resultset to table to see what I was getting and is empty` - all you had to do was add a `System.out.println(...)` statement inside the loop to see what values are in the ResultSet. Keep your debugging simple. System.out.priintln(...) is your fried to determine if your logic flow is what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

I like @camickr's comment, so am revising my answer. Try populating the model from the resultset, then declaring the JComboBox:

```
MutableComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
while (rs.next()){ 
    model.addItem(rs.getString("achooserfill"));
}
JComboBox achooser = new JComboBox(model);
```

Comment: Yes, but the default model is the DefaultComboBoxModel.

Comment: Note that it's been a while since I worked with Swing. You might find it works better to declare the model, add the line items to the model, then create the chooser after the model has been populated.

Comment: @BillHorvath thanks for your response and the information, I created the model but is not working, so if I understand properly what I should try to do is create a DefaultCombobox model, add the items to the model and after that assign the model to the chooser? thanks once more

Comment: @AlexGalvis, There is no need to do that. The default model is the DefaultComboBoxModel as I already explained. Don't get side tracked. If the removeAllItems() method works if proves that you can dynamically change the data.

Comment: `Try populating the model from the resultset,` - how do you even know there is data in the ResultSet? A question like this should not even be asked. This should first be tested using static hardcoded data to prove the logic to add items to the combo box is being invoked.

Comment: I agree in principle, but that wasn't the question that was asked, and in any case, if there's nothing in the result set, the model (and hence the combo box) will be empty.

Comment: `but that wasn't the question that was asked` - yes but you sometimes need to read between the lines to understand the context of the entire question. Whenever I see a question regarding a ResultSet the first thing I ask the OP is to get rid of the ResultSet and hard code the data rather than make guesses that put the OP on a wild goose chase. Then we have more information to solve the problem.

Comment: Also, you should not be suggesting to create a new JComboBox. You should just update the existing combo box by using the `setModel(...)` method if you use this approach. This way you don't need to worry about adding the newly created combo box to the frame and revalidating the frame.

Comment: Yup; I'll buy that - `setModel` would be much better. Good catch.